# how to add some data to sqlite database or sharedPrefence when installing apk

Tags: android

how to add some data to sqlite database or sharedPrefence when installing apk, which means the application has not been run once.

Comment: I do not think you can run any custom code when installing an app. Besides, you wouldn't have sharedpreferences or sqlite db if the app had never run.

Answer (score 1):

On SplashScreen, you can use boolean value to detect whether its first install or not. If it is first install, set the default values there, otherwise skip that.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String alreadyInstalled = prefs.getBoolean("alreadyInstalled",false);
if(!alreadyInstalled){
     prefs.edit().putBoolean("alreadyInstalled",true).apply();
     // Do your initialization of default values here.
}
```

Comment: thank you, can write sharedPrefences if the application has not been run once?

Comment: You can do that while launching the app (i.e., opening app's first screen), not before installing it.

Answer (score 0):

I run this in my Application Class. It is a little bit more powerful because it can track updates as well. `previous` will be `0` on first install.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static SharedPreferences sPrefs = null;

    /**
     * Corresponds to the version of the app.
     */
    private static final String PREF_APP_VERSION_NAME = "app_version_name";

    /**
     * Corresponds to the version code of the app.
     */
    private static final String PREF_APP_VERSION_CODE = "app_version_code";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        sPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        final int lastVersionCode = sPrefs.getInt(PREF_APP_VERSION_CODE, 0);
        final String lastVersionName = sPrefs.getString(PREF_APP_VERSION_NAME, null);
        if (BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE != sPrefs.getInt(PREF_APP_VERSION_CODE, 0) ||
                !BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME.equals(lastVersionName)) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "App update detected " + lastVersionName + " → " + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
            runOncePerVersion(lastVersionCode, BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE, lastVersionName, BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
            sPrefs.edit()
                    .putString(PREF_APP_VERSION_NAME, BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
                    .putInt(PREF_APP_VERSION_CODE, BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE)
                    .apply();
        }
    }


    /**
     * This method is to be called only when the app version code has changed.
     *
     * @param current      the current app version code
     * @param previousName {@link BuildConfig#VERSION_NAME} of previous install if known
     * @param currentName  {@link BuildConfig#VERSION_NAME} of current install
     */
    private void runOncePerVersion(int previous,
                                   int current,
                                   @Nullable String previousName,
                                   @NonNull String currentName) {
        UpdateNotifier.runOncePerVersion(this);
        Track.appUpdated(previousName, currentName);
        //Initialize your database from the assets folder
    }
}
```

When you have a custom application class, you must declare it in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:name=".app.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```